# How To Create A Navbar With SemiTransparent Background In HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, background, navbar, transparency

I'm writing code using HTML and CSS for my website, and I'm trying to make it so that the background behind the navbar is semi-transparent, but I don't want the entire nav/text to be transparent at all.

The website has a black background and all the text is white, and it's a single-scroll page. The idea is that as the user navigates down the site, the navbar will have a semitransparent black bar behind it so that the navbar doesn't get lost when a user scrolls it over a white image / other white text (since the nav text is also white). I know how to change the transparency of the entire navbar, but is there a way to just change the transparency of the nav background?

Currently, I've tried setting the background color to black and then setting the opacity property to 0.5, but this ends up affecting the entire nav bar instead of just the background. I also tried adding a class to the nav and adding background properties to the class, but with the same result.

```
    nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed; 
  background-color: black;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;   
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the opacity parameter in the *rgba()* color definition?

```
nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0); // Some old browsers might not accept the opacity parameter
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Considering that your background is white and also the text's color is white, it should do the trick.